# How to pass variable from java application to R shiny Server?

Tags: java, r, shiny

I am trying to **integrate R shiny with i2b2**.

In order to do that we need to send a integer variable from java to R shiny.
I have following queries-

1.How to create a connection between Java and R?

2.How to send variable from java to R?

3.How to get/receive  variable in R from java?

Answer (score 0):

You can't send variables across the language. You can send the values across the language using below ways,

1. REST endpoints - works across languages even commandline using curl / wget / browser http request plugins like postman...
2. SOAP (Interoperable across languages based on WSDL)
3. IDL - its older way to communicate across languages but previous ways are recommended ways.
4. You can write custom one like socket programming and share what ever you want across languages with both parties agreed payload structure.